# Find each element that is less than some element to its right

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, optimization, vectorization

I need to find elements of a vector that are less than one of more elements that come after it. It's easy to do in a loop:

```
x = some_vector_values;
for m = 1 : length(x)
  if( any( x(m+1:end) > x(m) )
    do_such_and_such;
  end
end
```

but the speed is killing me. I'm scratching my head trying to come up with an efficient work-around but am coming up blank. The array length can be on the order of thousands and I need to do this for many different arrays.

Comment: can't you first sort the vector? Then for sure you know that the numbers after a specific number are smaller (bigger) than that.

Comment: Some sample input and output to showcase your requirements?

Comment: Try running the profiler, what causes the major cpu time, the loop / condition or "do_such_and_such"? What dimension is x?

Comment: I concur with @NKN.  Note that `sort` can also return the original indices of the sorted element.

Comment: @NKK The order can't change. It's already the result of sorting a different arary.

Comment: @Daniel It's the `if` comparison within the loop.

Comment: What's the maximum size of your `x`?

Comment: @Divakar It could go up to >20e3.

Comment: What would you like to do after the if statement?

Comment: @RDizzl3 What I am after are the indices of the elements that meet the criteria, so the contents of if-clause is more for illustration/structure than anything else.

Comment: Ok cool, I wrote a solution that will find the indices of such. It scales fairly well for vector sizes up to about 10000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your algorithm is so slow since `if any(...)`has to check `n` items on the first iteration, then `n-1` items on the second iteration ... until checking a single item in the last iteration. Overal it thus has to do roughly `n^2/2` comparisons, so its running time is quadratic as a function of the length of the input vector!

One solution that is linear in time and memory might be to first calculate a vector with the maximum from that point until the end, which can be calculated in one backwards pass 
(you could call this a reversed cumulative maximum, which [cannot be vectorized](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/237000)). After this, this vector is compared directly to `x` (untested):

```
% calculate vector mx for which mx(i) = max(x(i:end))
mx = zeros(size(x));
mx(end) = x(end);
for i = length(x)-1:-1:1 % iterate backwards
    mx(i) = max(x(i), mx(i+1));
end

for i = 1:length(x) - 1
    if mx(i) > x(i)
        do_such_and_such(i);
    end
end
```

In case you don't care about the order in which `do_such_and_such` is executed, these for loops can even be combined like so:

```
mx = x(end);
for i = length(x)-1:-1:1 % iterate backwards
    if x(i) < mx
        do_such_and_such(i);
    end
    mx = max(x(i), mx); % maximum of x(i:end)
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I got several good answers, but this one was both simple and the fastest. Tremendously helpful, and not just for this specific problem; I feel like I learned something for future reference.

Answer (score 10):

This uses a [divide-and-conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) approach (similar to binary search):

1. Find the maximum of the vector.
2. All elements to its left are accepted, whereas the maximum itself is rejected.
3. For those elements to the right of the maximum, apply step 1.

Although I haven't done a careful analysis, I think average complexity is *O*(*n*), or at most *O*(*n* log *n*). Memory is *O*(*n*).

The result is a logical vector `ind` that contains `true` for accepted elements and `false` for rejected elements. The final result would be `x(ind)`.

```
x = [3 4 3 5 6 3 4 1];
n = numel(x);
ind = false(1,n); %// intiallization
s = 1; %// starting index of the part of x that remains to be analyzed
while s <= n %// if s > n we have finished
    [~, m] = max(x(s:end)); %// index of maximum within remaining part of x
    ind(s:s-2+m) = true; %// elements to its left are accepted
    s = s+m; %// update start of remaining part
end
```

Running time could be reduced a little by changing the `while` condition to `while s < n`,  because the last element is always rejected.

Comment: Yes! This must be the logic for higher data! +1

Comment: I guess this is `O(n log(n))` running time overall, not `O(log(n))`. I think my solution is `O(n)`.

Comment: @BasSwinckels You're right, finding the `max` introduces a linear factor. Corrected

Comment: @BasSwinckels On second thought, perhaps it's O(n). On average, I compute the maximum of n elements, then of n/2 elements, then of n/4 elements... which sums 2*n

Comment: You are probably correct, it should be `O(n)` in the optimal case (maximum at end) and average case (like you explained), but `O(n^2)` in the worst case (when x is strictly decreasing).

Answer (score 6):

**One-liner version**

```
comparisons = any(triu(bsxfun(@gt,x(:).',x(:))),2)
```

Comment: For large vectors (`numel(x)=10000`) this solution is slower.

Comment: @Daniel It's because you are stretching `bsxfun` there, as pointed out by @natan.

Comment: Thank you. Even if not ideal in the worst case, this is much much much faster in most cases and has been extremely helpful.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Awesome! Faster with smaller datasizes I am guessing!

Comment: Yeah, but vectors of size of a few thousand are the most common. I'm still looking at the other answer to see how it performs on the larger cases.

Comment: This solution uses `O(n^2)` memory.

Comment: Issues of complexity aside, you don't get a cleaner answer than this. However, I'd consider enforcing dimensionality of `x` (i.e. input `x(:)` or do a check.

Comment: @chappjc Appreciate the bug-finding effort there, edited! Good to see you around!

Answer (score 6):

This should be an algorithm that takes O(n) time and O(n) memory: Label the last element in your array the maximum element. Iterate backwards over the array. Whenever you have an element smaller than your maximum, save it. Otherwise, it becomes your new maximum. This should get you all of the elements you need with a single pass.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to find elements that are less than some element to its right, you can do this also:

```
x = some_values'; % x should be a column vector to use this
h = hankel(x);
m = max(h,[],2);
f = find(x<m) %returns indices or f = (a<m) %returns true/false
```

The hankel matrix will show the elements to the right as it goes down the rows.

Then you can use the indices or true/false to iterate through a for loop and perform some operations. Here is an example:

```
x =

     9
     8
    16
    16
     4
    10
     9
    13
    15
     1

>> h = hankel(x)

h =

     9     8    16    16     4    10     9    13    15     1
     8    16    16     4    10     9    13    15     1     0
    16    16     4    10     9    13    15     1     0     0
    16     4    10     9    13    15     1     0     0     0
     4    10     9    13    15     1     0     0     0     0
    10     9    13    15     1     0     0     0     0     0
     9    13    15     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
    13    15     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    15     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

>> m = max(h,[],2)

m =

    16
    16
    16
    16
    15
    15
    15
    15
    15
     1

>> f = find(a<m)

f =

     1
     2
     5
     6
     7
     8
```

Comment: This solution uses `O(n^2)` memory.

Answer (score 0):

@NKN has it right.  Sort.

```
x = some_vector_values;  

[Y,I]=sort(x);  %sort in order, get indices
dy=gradient(Y); %get difference vector same size as input vector
ind=find(dy~=0);%ignore places that are equal to the value of interest

for m = 1 : length(ind)
    do_such_and_such to Y(ind(m));
end
```

Best of luck

Comment: Maybe I am missing something obvious, but I don't see how this would work. There are two criterion: 1) A > B, and 2) A is to the right of B.

Comment: @BasSwinckels - for compiled software yes.  For interpreted - maybe not.  The sort builtin is likely compiled, your script - notsomuch.  I've seen compiled run 1000x faster than interpreted, but your mileage can vary.  The speed comparison between a compiled sort versus an interpreted sort when form is O(n log(n)) is O( 1000*n log(1000*n) / n log(n) ) or about 3000 * O(n log(n)).  The builtins are screaming fast.

Comment: Matlab has a pretty good JIT these days, which especially for simple loops should come to within a small factor of compiled code. This constant factor might be smaller than log(n) for big arrays.

Comment: This answer does not satisfy the criterion of problem.