# Calculate a "running" maximum of a vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have the following matrix which keeps track of the starting and ending points of data ranges (the first column represents `"starts"` and the second column represents the `"ends"`):

```
myMatrix = [
    162   199; %// this represents the range 162:199
    166   199; %// this represents the range 166:199
    180   187; %// and so on...
    314   326;
    323   326;
    397   399;
    419   420;
    433   436;
    576   757;
    579   630;
    634   757;
    663   757;
    668   757;
    676   714;
    722   757;
    746   757;
    799   806;
    951   953;
    1271  1272
];
```

I need to eliminate all the ranges (ie. rows) which are contained within a larger range present in the matrix.  For example the ranges `[166:199]` and `[180:187]` are contained within the range `[162:199]` and thus, rows 2 and 3 would need to be removed.

The solution I thought of was to calculate a sort of "running" `max` on the second column to which subsequent values of the column are compared to determine whether or not they need to be removed.  I implemented this with the use of a `for` loop as follows:

```
currentMax = myMatrix(1,2); %//set first value as the maximum
[sizeOfMatrix,~] = size(myMatrix); %//determine the number of rows
rowsToRemove = false(sizeOfMatrix,1); %//pre-allocate final vector of logicals
for m=2:sizeOfMatrix
    if myMatrix(m,2) > currentMax %//if new max is reached, update currentMax...
        currentMax = myMatrix(m,2);
    else
        rowsToRemove(m) = true; %//... else mark that row for removal
    end
end
myMatrix(rowsToRemove,:) = [];
```

This correctly removes the "redundant" ranges in `myMatrix` and produces the following matrix:

```
myMatrix =
         162         199
         314         326
         397         399
         419         420
         433         436
         576         757
         799         806
         951         953
        1271        1272
```

Onto the questions:

1) It would seem that there has to be a better way of calculating a "running" `max` than a `for` loop.  I looked into `accumarray` and `filter`, but could not figure out a way to do it with those functions.  Is there a potential alternative that skips the `for` loop (some kind of vectorized code that is more efficient)?

2) Is there a completely different (that is, more efficient) way to accomplish the final goal of removing all the ranges that are contained within larger ranges in `myMatrix`?  I don't know if I'm over-thinking this whole thing...

Comment: how big will this matrix be? If it's not too big, I don't see anything wrong with pairwise comparisons

Comment: `myMatrix` will likely not go beyond 100 rows or so.  The thing is I will have a very large number of these matrices on which I will need to run this.

Comment: There is a thread [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/237000) about implementing a cummulative max function, which I believe is the answer to your first question. I've used the algorithm in a similar manner (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142836/find-each-element-that-is-less-than-some-element-to-its-right)) and found its performance to be good.

Comment: What if the first column is not sorted? Your loopy solution doesn't seem to be working with such a situation. Or are you assuming that it won't be case with your actual dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Approach #1

`bsxfun` based brute-force approach -

```
myMatrix(sum(bsxfun(@ge,myMatrix(:,1),myMatrix(:,1)') & ...
    bsxfun(@le,myMatrix(:,2),myMatrix(:,2)'),2)<=1,:)
```

**Few explanations on the proposed solution:**

1. Compare all `starts` indices against each other for "contained-ness" and similarly for `ends` indices. Note that the "contained-ness" criteria has to be for either of these two :

   - Greater than or equal to for `starts` and lesser than or equal to for `ends`
   - Lesser than or equal to for `starts` and greater than or equal to for `ends`.

   I just so happen to go with the first option.
2. See which rows satisfy at least one "contained-ness" and remove those to have the desired result.

---

### Approach #2

If you are okay with an output that has sorted rows according to the first column and if there are lesser number of `local max's`, you can try this alternative approach -

```
myMatrix_sorted = sortrows(myMatrix,1);
col2 = myMatrix_sorted(:,2);
max_idx = 1:numel(col2);
while 1
    col2_selected = col2(max_idx);
    N = numel(col2_selected);
    labels = cumsum([true ; diff(col2_selected)>0]);
    idx1 = accumarray(labels, 1:N ,[], @(x) findmax(x,col2_selected));
    if numel(idx1)==N
        break;
    end
    max_idx = max_idx(idx1);
end
out = myMatrix_sorted(max_idx,:); %// desired output
```

Associated function code -

```
function ix = findmax(indx, s)
[~,ix] = max(s(indx));
ix = indx(ix);
return;
```

Comment: +1 That would have been my approach too. I mean approach 1, of course :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo haha I thought that was for approach #2! :) Well regarding approach #2, I am not liking the use of `anonymous function` there, don't trust that for performance.

Comment: Approach 2? Nah! Where's that "nay loops, yay bsxfun"? :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo Well.. sometimes we need to break our own rules too! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following for the "running maximum" problem (but have no comment on its efficiency relative to other solutions):

```
function x = cummax(x)
% Cumulative maximum along dimension 1
% Adapted from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/126657
% Is recursive, but magically so, such that the number of recursions is proportional to log(n).

n = size(x, 1);
%fprintf('%d\n', n)
if n == 2
    x(2, :) = max(x);
elseif n  % had to add this condition relative to the web version, otherwise it would recurse infinitely with n=0
    x(2:2:n, :) = cummax(max(x(1:2:n-1, :), x(2:2:n,   :)));
    x(3:2:n, :) =        max(x(3:2:n,   :), x(2:2:n-1, :));
end
```