# Find the number of inversions in Matlab

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, optimization, inversion

On the way of finding number of inversions in array by divide-and-conquer approach I faced with a problem of implementing merge-step: we have two sorted arrays, the task is to count the number of cases when an element of the first array is greater than an element from the second.

For example, if the arrays are `v1 = [1,2,4], v2 = [0,3,5]`, we should count 4 inversions.

So, I implemented the merge-step in Matlab, but I stuck with the problem of how to make it fast.

Firstly, I've tried brute-force approach with

```
tempArray = arrayfun(@(x) length(find(v2>x)), v1)
```

It works too slow as well as the next snippet

```
l = 1;
s = 0;
for ii = 1:n1 
    while(l <= n2 && p1(ii)>p2(l))
        l = l + 1;
    end
    s = s + l - 1;
end
```

Is there a good way to make it faster?

**Edit**

Thank you for your answers and approaches! I find interesting things for my further work.

Here is the snippet, which supposed to be the fastest I've tried

```
n1 = length(vec1); n2 = length(vec2);

uniteOne = [vec1, vec2];

[~, d1] = sort(uniteOne);
[~, d2] = sort(d1); % Find ind-s IX such that B(IX) = A, where B = sort(A)
vec1Slice = d2(1:n1);
finalVecToSolve = vec1Slice - (1:n1);

sum(finalVecToSolve)
```

Comment: [`Find each element that is less than some element to its right`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142836/find-each-element-that-is-less-than-some-element-to-its-right) might be relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another brute-force approach with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
sum(reshape(bsxfun(@gt,v1(:),v2(:).'),[],1))
```

Or, as @thewaywewalk has mentioned in the comments, use `nnz` to replacing `summing` -

```
nnz(bsxfun(@gt,v1(:),v2(:).'))
```

Comment: I was still thinking on how to `bsxfun` it :(

Comment: instead of `sum` and `reshape` you could use `nnz(bsxfun(@gt,v1(:),v2(:).'))`

Comment: @thewaywewalk Yeah that's another way to do it I guess, but there was these benchmarks we did that showed `nnz` to be slower than `sum`, but in this case might be offsetted by the reshape.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Also that might be good for *golfing* if not for performance :) Do you mind if I add `nnz` to it?

Comment: sure I wouldn't have left it as a comment otherwise ;)

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks! :)

Comment: This would have been my approach too. Since you had already taken it, I had to look for another one, which turns out to be quite efficient

Answer (score 4):

### Code

```
n = numel(v1);
[~, ind_sort] = sort([v1 v2]);
ind_v = ind_sort<=n;
result = sum(find(ind_v))-n*(n+1)/2;
```

### Explanation

`n` denotes the length of the input vectors. `ind_v` is a vector of length `2*n` that represents the values of `v1` and `v2` sorted together, with *one* indicating a value from `v1` and *zero* indicating a value from `v2`. For your example,

```
v1 = [1,2,4];
v2 = [0,3,5];
```

we have

```
ind_v =
     0     1     1     0     1     0
```

The first entry of `ind_v` is *zero*. This means that the lowest value from `v1` and `v2` (which is `0`) belongs to `v2`. Then there is a *one* because the second-lowest value (which is `1`) belongs to `v1`. The last entry of `ind_v` is *zero* because the largest value of the input vectors (which is `5`) belongs to `v2`.

From this `ind_v` it's easy to compute the result. Namely, we only need to **count how many *zeros* there are to the left of each *one*, and sum all those counts**.

We don't even need to do the counts; we can infer them **just from the position of each *one***. The number of *zeros* to the left of the first *one* is the position of that *one* minus `1`. The number of *zeros* to the left of the second *one* is its position minus `2`. And so on. Thus `sum(find(ind_v)-(1:n))` would give the desired result. But `sum(1:n)` is just `n*(n+1)/2`, and so the result can be simplified to `sum(find(ind_v))-n*(n+1)/2`.

### Complexity

Sorting the vectors is the limiting operation here, and requires `O(2*n*log(2*n))` arithmetic comparisons. Brute force, on the contrary, requires `O(n^2)` comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

One explicit approach could be to subtract your elements and see where they're negative:

```
v1 = [1,2,4];
v2 = [0,3,5];

mydiffs = zeros(length(v1), length(v2));
for ii = 1:length(v1)
    mydiffs(ii,:) = v2 - v1(ii);
end

test = sum(reshape(mydiffs,[],length(v1)*length(v2)) < 0)
```

Which returns:

```
test =

     4
```

This isn't the prettiest approach and there's definitely room for improvement. I also doubt it's faster than the `bsxfun` approach.

Edit1: An [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) approach, which looks tidier but isn't necessarily faster than the loop.

```
test = arrayfun(@(x) (v2 - x) < 0, v1, 'UniformOutput', false);
inversions = sum([test{:}]);
```

Edit2: A [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) approach

```
inversions = nnz(repmat(v2, length(v2), 1) - repmat(v1', 1, length(v1)) < 0)
```

Comment: This is a nice approach too.

Comment: bsxfun is memory hungry, which slows it down stretched to the limits, so I guess it would depend on the array sizes.